# Colorbox : Content closes on click

Tags: php, jquery, html, colorbox

I'm pretty new to web dev and i'm having an issue with the colorbox plugin.
Everything works correctly when first opening the page.
[Default look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uBPHv.png)

Each of the images are links that when clicked on open the respective colorbox.
[When clicking colorbox is displayed correctly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/faaoW.png)

When clicking on the close icon or clicking on the background overlay the colorbox closes as it should, but when i click on the colorbox content itself the colorbox stops displaying content and the border and background overlay stays.
[Error i'm describing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UxJAN.png)

What I would like to do is to disable the clicking functionality of the content so that it only closes when clicking the close icon or the background overlay.

This is my code for the page itself (html/php).

```
<section class="invitados contenedor seccion">
    <h2>Nuestros Invitados</h2>
    <ul class="lista-invi clearfix">
        <?php while ($invitados = $resultado->fetch_assoc()) { ?>

            <li>
                <div class="invi">
                    <a class="invitado-info" href="#invitado<?php echo $invitados['invitado_id'] ?>"> 
                    <img src="img/<?php echo $invitados['url_imagen'] ?>" alt="Imagen De Invitado 1" />
                    <p><?php echo $invitados['nombre_invitado'] . ' ' . $invitados['apellido_invitado'] ?></p>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </li>
            <div style="display:none;">
                <div class="invitado-info" id="invitado<?php echo $invitados['invitado_id'] ?>">
                    <h2><?php echo $invitados['nombre_invitado'] . ' ' . $invitados['apellido_invitado'] ?></h2>
                    <img src="img/<?php echo $invitados['url_imagen'] ?>" alt="Imagen De Invitado 1" />
                    <p><?php echo $invitados['descripcion'] ?></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        <?php } ?>
    </ul>
</section>
```

And the jquery function

```
$('.invitado-info').colorbox({inline:true, width:'50%' });
```

Sorry if class names and vars look weird they are in spanish and thanks in advance to anyone that helps.